# Is it possible remove the root directory from find command output?

Tags: unix, find

I want to move some files around and thought that find would be a good option to select the correct files. So I look for the files:

```sh
find somedir -iname "somefile"
somedir/subdir1/subdir2/somefile
somedir/subdir2/somefile
somedir/subdir3/somefile
somedir/subdir4/somefile
somedir/subdir5/somefile
```

Thats not very helpful for what I'm planning next. What I need would be:

```sh
find somedir -iname "somefile" -magic-option
subdir1/subdir2/somefile
subdir2/somefile
subdir3/somefile
subdir4/somefile
subdir5/somefile
```

What would `-magic-option` be?

Obviously a simple printout is not what I had in mind. The final command will also have a '-exec'. Something like:

```sh
find somedir -iname "somefile" -magic-option -exec some_command 'somedir/{}' 'someotherdir/{}' ';'
```

I'm surprised I couldn't find anything as removing the root directory from the result seem a pretty obvious feature.

If the answer to the question is **'NO'** then that's ok. I have a crude plan B using `pushd` and `for` loops. But `find` would be more elegant.

Comment: Are you talking about ignoring the root level of the directory structure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is non-standard, but with gnu find (4.6.0.225-235f), you could do:

```
find somedir -iname somefile -printf %P\\n
```

From the documentation:

```
%P     File's name with the name of the starting-point under which it was found removed.
```

If you want a generic solution, it seems simple enough to filter the output with something like:

```
find somedir -iname somefile | sed 's@^[^/]*/@@'
```

Both of those solutions will fail horribly if any of your filenames contain a newline, so if you want a robust solution you would want to do something like:

```
find somedir -iname somefile -printf %P\\0
```

Comment: Yes, that worked. Of corse i won't be able to use `-exec` that way but a `| xargs` is fine as well.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you need the mindepth flag.

```
find somedir -mindepth 2 -iname "somefile"
```

This will ignore the directory you are in and search from one level down recursively.